# WWW HTTP - sometimes URL doesn't have www

Tags: http, url, web

I have this thing in mind over time about the difference in URL, like:

http://www.google.com and 
http://mail.google.com

In first, we mention www and in the second one there isn't any mention of www.

What does www mean? Can we have http://google.com? Have www what does it mean, while some sites don't have it? (I am taking this example as i can readily see this, nothing particlular for google).

Please need to understand the clear difference between them.

Comment: **`W`** `orld` **`W`** `ide` **`W`** `eb`.

Answer (score 2):

The domain name is google. WWW is just a subdomain of google.

In some organisations the domain name is used for intranet, too.

For example (just an example) google.com is used in the intranet of google inc. but they also have a website and to make this website public www point to this website

for example you have a Server with apache.

apache manage now if you have the right to see the site or not or to redirect you.

- If you go to google.com -> if Lan then xxx else redirect:
  www.google.com
- if you go to maps.google.com -> if lan then xxx else
  redirect www.google.com/maps/preview

and so on, but if you go to www.google.com or you are redirected to it then you have the right to se

> /var/www/

where the website is.
If you are an employer by google and try to open google.com in your office you will see some other sites that only employes will see.

Comment: is google.com domain or just google? In that case can there be a new company with name google.txt?

Comment: domainname.tld tdl = topleveldomain so it could be possible to get a domain ith google.txt but txt is not a tld

Comment: Assuming we got tld as txt; would google.txt be another company? Is "google" the key over which copyright be?

Comment: a company and a domain name are two different things. But like you said google has a copyright so google.txt would be in this case the same company beceause no one other than google has the right to use the name google.

Answer (score 0):

www is just a common subdomain.

Answer (score -1):

Basicly "www" is the subdomain where your site is located.
If you work in LAN, it will be replaced by "localhost" or an ip (192.168.x.x)

Nowadays, internets browsers don't display the www because it is obvious.
And browser add automaticly "www" in the URL address if you don't write it.

By this way I mean that "www" is so common that it's not usefull to specify it

Comment: this is false it is a difference if you have www or not. www is a subdomain